# Sending WolframAlpha questions to WolframCommunity

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

It's well established that WolframAlpha questions are discouraged on this site.  I recommend that, in closing comments, we now send users to the new [WolframCommunity](http://community.wolfram.com/) site.  We could even point them straight to the [WolframAlpha group](http://community.wolfram.com/content?curTag=wolfram%20alpha).

Comment: I think that sounds reasonable. At least, they now have a place to ask them.