# Question about Wolframalpha itself

Tags: support, allowed-questions, asking-questions

I have to ask a question about WolframAlpha itself: Can I ask it on the site?, or is it off topic.

Comment: According to [Sending WolframAlpha questions to WolframCommunity](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1066), seems it's off-topic.

Answer (score 4):

According to https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

> Some kinds of questions are considered off-topic:
>
> - Questions on Wolfram Alpha (but questions on using Wolfram Alpha within Mathematica are okay).

And following advice on [Sending WolframAlpha questions to WolframCommunity](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1066/sending-wolframalpha-questions-to-wolframcommunity) you can try on community.wolfram.com.